# Make Selenium choose specific Dropdown menu PYTHON3

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need Selenium to choose menu with VALUE that I obtained from crawling.
Here is the portion of HTML code of Dropdown menu:

```
<select class="graySelect" name="sch_bub_nm" id="sch_bub_nm" 
title="Case Number" onchange="onChangeBub();">
<option value="000100">Case1</option>
<option value="000200">Case2</option>
<option value="000201">Case3</option>
.
.
.
```

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
def MenuChoose():
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sch_bub_nm').click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="sch_bub_nm"]/option[1]")
```

As you can see, I tried to choose the menu, and I got stuck as `xpath` showed no value that I can direct code to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Select` to get the dropdown value. I have given 3 options to select value.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sch_bub_nm"))
select.select_by_index(1) #select index value
select.select_by_visible_text("Case2") # select visible text
select.select_by_value("000201") # Select option value
```

Let me know if this work.

Comment: I'm guessing both of the comment works, but it looks like I have to select iframe that contains dropdown menu within webpage first for this to work. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a select element in order to interact with it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sch_bub_nm'))
select.select_by_index(1)  # Choose the position you want
```

Check the [selenium-python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html) documentation to see more options for select.

Comment: I'm guessing both of the comment works, but it looks like I have to select iframe that contains dropdown menu within webpage first for this to work. Thanks anyways!